# How to use attribute selector for an angular2 standalone compon

Tags: angular

I am seeing in quite a few literature where and angular component selector can be enclosed in sqare brackets similar to a directive selector. However, it is not working for me:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core'
import { RxIf } from '@rx-angular/template/if'

import { DxAbstractBaseComponent } from './dx-abstract-base-component'


@Component({
   selector: '[dx-custom-text-box]',
   standalone: true,
   imports: [RxIf],
   template: `<ng-container *rxIf="visible"> <ng-content /></ng-container>`,
   styles: [],
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DxCustomTextBoxComponent extends DxAbstractBaseComponent {}
```

I am trying to use it the following way: **Is it allowed?**

```
      <dxi-item>
         <div *dxTemplate>
            <dx-text-box
               #dxTextBox
               (onValueChanged)="onDxTextBoxValueChanged()"
               [(value)]="$name().first"
               dx-custom-text-box
               label = 'First *'
            />
       </div>
    </dxi-item>
```

I get the following linting error with failure to compile:

```
ESLint: The selector should be used as an element (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-03)(@angular-eslint/component-selector)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use as selector some between `[` `]` you can use in a "html tag", typical a div

```
<div dx-custom-text-box></div>
```

but you can not use in a ng-container

NOTE: I think (but not sure) you need use `<ng-content></ng-content>` instead of the "abreviated" `<ng-container/>`